# How come my toString doesn't return the string builder?

Tags: java, tostring, stringbuilder

I need to make a binary tree using Nodes with data, left, and right.
In my toString() method, I'm using a string builder and a preOrderTraverse method.

My toString() doesn't return anything however. Any ideas why this could be?

```
private void preOrderTraverse(Node node, int depth, StringBuilder sb) {
    for (int i = 1; i < depth; i++) {
        sb.append("  ");
    }
    if (node == null) {
        sb.append("null\n");
    } else {
        sb.append(node.data.toString());
        sb.append("\n");
        preOrderTraverse(node.left, depth + 1, sb);
        preOrderTraverse(node.right, depth + 1, sb);
    }
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    preOrderTraverse(root, 0, sb);
    return sb.toString();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BRT b = new BRT();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        Random generator = new Random();
        Integer randomIndex = generator.nextInt( 11 );
        b.add(randomIndex);
    }

    b.toString();

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you passing sb into preOrderTraverse. A better design would be to have preorderTraverse return a String and you could just return that value directly from the toString method

Comment: @Dace passing StringBuilder will give far better performance, because new String objects aren't being created everywhere. You would really notice it for larger trees.

Comment: Yep, missed the recursive calls. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to output it.

```
System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override toString() by simply printing the Object, Like this

```
System.out.println(b);
```

And also you are passing value of Depth which is initially zero and in the `preOrderTraverse` class comparing `i < depth`, depth value id zero and i is initialized to one so the loop will never execute.